# Slider with first item big on owl-carousel

Tags: javascript, css, owl-carousel

I have a slider with 3 or more images to load. This content is dynamic, but I need that always the first item has a big size, like this:

[image]

How could I do that with Owl-Carousel? I do it with fixed sizes, but when the user loads a new image, it no longer works and it looks awful.

Thank you for your advice!

Answer (score 0):

You can first try to adjust your CSS like this:

```
.owl-carousel{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    max-width:100%;
    background-color: #a49e9e;
    height: 100%;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.size625x488{
    width: 625px;
    height: 488px;
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
    margin: 1%;
}

._2ndColumn{
    width: 50%;
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
    margin: 1%;
    max-height: 100%;
}

.size462x216_1{
    background-color: #696868;
    width: 462px;
    height: 216px;
    margin: 1%;
}

.size462x216_2{
    background-color: #696868;
    width: 462px;
    height: 216px;
    margin: 1%;
    margin-top: 8%;
}
```

And your html something like this

```
<section class="wrapper">
  <div class="owl-carousels owl-themes" id="home-slider2">
    <div class="size625x488"> </div>
    <div class="_2ndColumn">
      <div class="size462x216_1"> </div>
      <div class="size462x216_2"> </div>
    </div>
  </div> <!--Display flex makes it easier to style-->
</section>
```